# Invalid operands - how to fix this short code?

Tags: c++

I should analyse some snippets and find the bugs and fix them. I got all of them, just a problem with this one:

```
class B {
public:
    int i;
    B(int i):i(i) {
    }
    B operator+(B& other) {
        B result(i+other.i);
        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    B* b0 = new B(100);
    B* b1 = new B(300);
    B* b2 = b1+b2; //invalid operands of types ‘B*’ and ‘B*’ to binary ‘operator+’
}
```

Don't understand the problem and dont know how to fix that. Could somebody explain to me the problem?

Comment: What on *earth* are you trying to accomplish by adding b1 and b2? Do you mean b0 + b1? b2 isn't even initialized when you try to use it. Adding pointers does not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

b1 and b2 are pointers (but I guess you want to add b0 and b1). Your operator may be called with `*b0 + *b1`, but the result is a `B`, not a `B*`. You also may want to set your operator method `const`, so as its `other` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference the pointers, and then construct a new object with that value:

```
B * b2 = new B(*b0 + *b1);
// don't forget to clean up b0, b1 and b2!
```

However, just **don't do this** at all. You probably don't need these variables to be dynamically allocated, so just allocate them automatically:

```
B b0(100);
B b1(300);
B b2 = b0 + b1;
```

Comment: thanks. At first i tought B *b2 = b0->B + b1->B; but thats of sure wrong. Sometimes i have really problems with pointers...

Comment: @Melson: Most of the time you shouldn't be writing any pointers at all in modern C++. Their use should be confined to very particular, well-defined situations only.

Answer (score -1):

You are using pointers to objects (i.e. the addresses of the objects), not objects themselves.

I think what you wanted to write was:

```
B b(100);
B b1(300);
B b2 = b1+b2;
```

Your code could be modified to compile thus:

```
B* b0 = new B(100);
B* b1 = new B(300);
B* b2 = &(*b1+*b2);
```

but you are now in **very** dangerous territory. The addition operator has created a variable on the stack, and you have taken the address of that variable. However, next time you use the stack (e.g. call another function), the variable will be trashed.

This shows the kind of pitfall you can easily fall into with C++!

Just to be absolutely clear **YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THIS**.

Comment: That is terrible - You are storing the address of a temporary in `b2`! The explanation isn't also very dangerous, because in general the destructor of the temporary will already have been executed by the time you assign the value.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I said (except for the bit about the destructor, because there isn't a destructor in that class). I think it is outrageous that you have marked my answer down.